# pythonで一致したIDを取得する処理の高速化

Tags: python

```
$ input_A
  @ID_1
  aaaa
  +
  nnnn
  @ID_2
  bbbb
  +
  nnnn
  ...
  @ID_50000000
  zzzz
  +
  nnnn

$ inputB
  ID_832-aaa
  ID_12020-aaa-bbb
  ID_1-nnn-nnn
  ID_9999-ddd-aaa-ccc
  ID_2-xxx-xxx
  ...
  ID_20000000-aaa
```

上記のような2つのファイルから、一致したinputBのID情報とinputAのID下の配列情報を取得したいと考えています。
どちらも2000万〜5000万件程度あります。
inputAの配列とIDはbiopythonというモジュールを使用して取得させ、下記のような処理を行いました。
しかし、配列数が多いためか処理時間がかかってしまい、数千万件処理するのに数百時間かかる見込みで実用的ではありません。
現実的な処理時間でこのような処理を行うにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

```
for a in seqIO.parse(inputA, 'fastq'):
    for b in inputB:
        if a.id == b.split('-')[0]
            result = ">" + str(b) + str(q.seq) + '\n'
```

下記のようなOutputを想定しています。

```
$ result
  >ID_1-nnn-nnn
  aaaa
  >ID_2-xxx-xxx
  bbbb
  ...
  >ID_50000000-aaa-bbb-ccc
  zzzz
```

---

追記
inputBのID番号(先頭から-まで)と、inputAのID(@より後ろ)が一致したinputBの行(resultの>行)と、その下にinputAの@の下の行を引用したファイルをresultとして作成しようとしています。
@ID_50000000の@はミスです。修正しました。
inputAの+行とその下は不要です。
inputAの@行は重複なし、inputBのID(ID_X)は重複ありですが、行全体(ID_X-abc-abc)は重複なしです。
pythonのバージョンは2.7.10を使用しています。

Comment: よくわからないのですが、「input_A」というファイルには1行目「@ID_1」、2行目「aaaa」、3行目「+」、4行目「nnnn」という4行で1つのIDという事でしょうか？「ID_50000000」に「@」がないのはミスでしょうか？そして、「input_A」と「input_B」のどことどこが紐づくのでしょうか？resultで「ID_1-nnn-nnn」が「 aaaa」と出力されていますが、「input_A」の2から4行目は不要という事でしょうか？補足をお願いします。

Comment: Python に拘らなければ、[lh3/seqtk: Toolkit for processing sequences in FASTA/Q formats](https://github.com/lh3/seqtk) というツールがあります。README に記載されていますが、`seqtk subseq in.fq name.lst > out.fq` などとします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

辞書オブジェクトを使うことで解決します。
（inputA の ID に重複がないことを前提としています。）

```
dict = {}

for a in seqIO.parse(inputA, 'fastq'):
    dict[a.id] = a

for b in inputB:
    bid = b.split('-')[0]
    if bid in dict
        result = ">" + str(b) + str(dict[bid].seq) + '\n'
```

現在の手法では inputA をループしている中で inputB をループしているため、計算量は `O( inputA * inputB )` となります。

これに対し、辞書を使うと inputA の内容を辞書に格納するループが `O( inputA )`、 inputB の内容で辞書を探すループが `O( inputB )` となり、全体で `O( inputA + inputB )` となります。
inputA と inputB はどちらも1000万のオーダーとのことなので、この変更により、ロジック的にはざっくり1000万倍ほど高速化すると期待できます。
（どこか別のところがボトルネックになります。IOとか。）

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 改善案を用いて再度実行してみたところ、3時間程度でなんとか計算が終わりました。
はやり数千万オーダーのファイルを扱うのは難しいですね…
大変参考になりました。